# Python: How can I drop the first 5 minutes of each day in my time serie?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, timedelta

I have a dataframe with columns: Date of a transaction , Time of the transaction and Price. I want to drop the first and last 5 minutes in each day.

Here is an example:

```
----------------------------------------
Date       | Time         | Price
----------------------------------------
03/03/2014 | 09:36:36.814 |  43.90
---------------------------------------
03/03/2014 | 09:37:02.381  | 43.40
---------------------------------------
03/03/2014 | 09:41:02.381  | 43.40
---------------------------------------
03/03/2014 | 09:50:02.381  | 43.40
---------------------------------------
```

I want to get this output:

```
----------------------------------------
Date       | Time         | Price
---------------------------------------
03/03/2014 | 09:50:02.381  | 43.40
---------------------------------------
```

I need to do this for each day of time serie.
I tried this code:

```
  trades14081.insert(2,'DateTime',pd.to_datetime(trades14081['Date']+trades14081['Time'], format = "%d/%m/%Y%H:%M:%S.%f" ))
delta=datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
i=0
j=0
start=[]
end=[]
while trades14081['Date'][i]==trades14081['Date'][j] and j<len(trades14081):
    if trades14081['DateTime'][j]-trades14081['DateTime'][i]<delta:
        j=j+1
    else:
        start.append(i)
        end.append(j)
        j=j+1
        while trades14081['Date'][i]==trades14081['Date'][j] and j<len(trades14081):
            j=j+1
        i=j
for i in range(len(start)):
    trades14081=trades14081.drop(trades14081.index[start[i]:end[i]])
```

But I keep on getting this error:

> KeyError: 19996

```
>      12             l.append(j)
>      13             j=j+1
> ---> 14             while trades14081['Date'][i]==trades14081['Date'][j]:
>      15                 j=j+1
>      16             i=j
```

19996 is the length of my dataframe trades14081.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share sample input and expected output? That'll make it clearer for us.

Comment: This problem domain looks like it's more suited to something like Observables.  RxJS/Marble diagrams http://rxmarbles.com/ - egghead.io and angular university have good course around this if you were coming at it from a JS perspective. Perhaps https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY would work - have never used it..

Answer (score 2):

#### `groupby` + Boolean indexing

You can and should avoid Python-level loops. Here you can use `groupby`:

```
# convert strings to timedelta
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])

# define offset from start to omit
offset = pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)

# apply Boolean filter to dataframe
res = df.loc[df['Time'] > df.groupby('Date')['Time'].transform('min') + offset]

print(res)

          Date     Time  Price
4  03/03/2014  09:40:00     41
5  03/03/2014  09:46:00     42
```